# Inaccurate camera calibration

Tags: c++, c, opencv, camera-calibration

I'm performing a camera application using OpenCV and the checkerboard-method. This is my input image:

[image: Input checkerboard before calibration]

This is the result after calibration:

[image: Calibrated image]

I added a red rectangle to visualise what is wrong: the spatial distortion is corrected but not very accurate, the result now has some other, non-linear distortions resulting in some non-parallel borders of the squares. The dots and crosshairs shown in the image are not used during calibration and the black-to-white fade in background does not have any influence, when I remove it, the result is the same.

What could be the reason for this?

This is how the correction is calculated at the moment (simplified pseudocode without any error checks and with some non-relevant parts missing). First calculation of the correction based on the checkerboard:

```
CvSize board_sz = cvSize( board_w, board_h );
//Allocate storage for the parameters according to total number of corners and number of snapshots
CvMat* image_points      = cvCreateMat(n_boards*board_total,2,CV_32FC1);
CvMat* object_points     = cvCreateMat(n_boards*board_total,3,CV_32FC1);
CvMat* point_counts      = cvCreateMat(n_boards,1,CV_32SC1);
CvMat* intrinsic_matrix  = cvCreateMat(3,3,CV_32FC1);
CvMat* distortion_coeffs = cvCreateMat(4,1,CV_32FC1);

CvPoint2D32f* corners = new CvPoint2D32f[ board_total ];

//Find chessboard corners:
cvFindChessboardCorners(gray_image, board_sz, corners,corner_count,CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH|CV_CALIB_CB_FILTER_QUADS|CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE );
  if (*corner_count!=board_total) cvFindChessboardCorners(gray_image, board_sz, corners,corner_count,CV_CALIB_CB_ADAPTIVE_THRESH|CV_CALIB_CB_NORMALIZE_IMAGE);

cvFindCornerSubPix(gray_image,corners, *corner_count, cvSize(11,11), cvSize(-1,-1), cvTermCriteria(CV_TERMCRIT_EPS+CV_TERMCRIT_ITER, 30, 0.1 ));

// Initialize the intrinsic matrix with both the two focal lengths in a ratio of 1.0
CV_MAT_ELEM(*intrinsic_matrix,float,0,0)=1.0f;   CV_MAT_ELEM(*intrinsic_matrix,float,0,1)=0.0f;   CV_MAT_ELEM(*intrinsic_matrix,float,0,2)=0.0f;
CV_MAT_ELEM(*intrinsic_matrix,float,1,0)=0.0f;   CV_MAT_ELEM(*intrinsic_matrix,float,1,1)=1.0f;   CV_MAT_ELEM(*intrinsic_matrix,float,1,2)=0.0f;
CV_MAT_ELEM(*intrinsic_matrix,float,2,0)=0.0f;   CV_MAT_ELEM(*intrinsic_matrix,float,2,1)=0.0f;   CV_MAT_ELEM(*intrinsic_matrix,float,2,2)=0.0f;

CV_MAT_ELEM(*intrinsic_matrix,float,0,0)=1.0; // fx
CV_MAT_ELEM(*intrinsic_matrix,float,1,1)=(1.0*calib_data->height)/calib_data->width; // fy
cvCalibrateCamera2(object_points, image_points, point_counts, cvGetSize(gray_image),
                     intrinsic_matrix, distortion_coeffs,
                     NULL,NULL,
                     CV_CALIB_FIX_ASPECT_RATIO);

cornerPoints=(struct camera_calib_point*)malloc(*corner_count*sizeof(struct camera_calib_point));
// calculate spatial correction matrix
{
   cv::Point2f src_vertices[4],dst_vertices[4];
   float       minx=1000000.0,miny=1000000.0,maxx=-1000000.0,maxy=-1000000.0;
   double      d;
   cv::Mat     warpMatrix;

   src_vertices[0]=corners[0];
   src_vertices[1]=corners[board_w-1];
   src_vertices[2]=corners[board_w*board_h-board_w];
   src_vertices[3]=corners[board_w*board_h-1];
   for (i=0; i<4; i++)
   {
      if (src_vertices[i].x<minx) minx=src_vertices[i].x;
      if (src_vertices[i].x>maxx) maxx=src_vertices[i].x;
      if (src_vertices[i].y<miny) miny=src_vertices[i].y;
      if (src_vertices[i].y>maxy) maxy=src_vertices[i].y;
   }
   dst_vertices[0].x=minx; dst_vertices[0].y=maxy;
   dst_vertices[1].x=maxx; dst_vertices[1].y=maxy;
   dst_vertices[2].x=minx; dst_vertices[2].y=miny;
   dst_vertices[3].x=maxx; dst_vertices[3].y=miny;
   warpMatrix=getPerspectiveTransform(src_vertices, dst_vertices);
}
// end of calculate spatial correction matrix
```

Then correction data are applied to an image this way:

```
/* Edit: missing part added */
cv::Size imageSize(handle->width,handle->height);

cv::initUndistortRectifyMap(handle->intrinsic, handle->distortion,cv::Mat(),
                            cv::getOptimalNewCameraMatrix(handle->intrinsic, handle->distortion,imageSize,1,imageSize,0),
                            imageSize, CV_16SC2,*handle->mapx,*handle->mapy);
/* End of edit: missing part added */


cv::remap(cv::cvarrToMat(sImage),dImage,*handle->mapx,*handle->mapy,cv::INTER_LINEAR);
cv::warpPerspective(dImage, dImage2,*handle->warpMtx,dImage.size(),cv::INTER_LINEAR,cv::BORDER_CONSTANT);
```

So...anybody an idea what could go wrong here?

Comment: I see you do calculate camera distortion(although only 4 coefficients) from a set of images but do you undistort the image (and points) before finding the warp matrix? Also depending on image quality detected corners may be a little off, besides it only finds imner corners (where squares touch), see if the 4 corners you use to find transformation are correct.

Comment: @IcedLance not sure what you mean with undistorting the image - what function would be used for this?

Comment: `undistort()` the exact call might difer from version to version (like it does with `cv::calibrateCamera` ) but heres a link to docs. https://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/imgproc/doc/geometric_transformations.html#undistort

Comment: @IcedLance sorry, I have simplified the code a bit too much: initUndistortRectifyMap() is used during correction of the image - I updated my original post

Comment: Just to make sure: after applying camera distortion correction you either need to find corners again or apply corrections to old corner points ( one way is `cv:undistortPoints` not sure how to do it with rectify maps), otherwise you calculate perspective transform as if it was still distorted but apply to undistorted image. Also using rectify maps is a bit too heavy of an approach if you only have one camera. undistort does a good enough job in simple cases so maybe look into using it unless you have reasons to stick with rectify maps.

Comment: @IcedLance great, dropping the rectify-stuff and using warpPerspective() only does the job, now it looks quite perfect!!!